# LINQ to Get All heirerichal children

Tags: c#, linq

I have been digging this quite a while.

```
public class Person
{
   public string Name { get; set; }    
   public string Age { get; set; }    
   public List<Person> Children { get; set; }    
}
```

I want a single LINQ query to find out "All the persons whose `Age > 4` in this collection".

Note: You have to traverse Collection of `Person` + Collection of `Children`, so each children object will have a collection of `Person` till `Children` becomes `null`.

Comment: Please, for the love of all that is holy, replace "Childrens" with "Children".

Comment: You could replace this class with `public class Person : List<Person> { public string Name { get; set; } public string Age { get; set; } }` and relieve yourself of the need to create the `Children` property each time. It will also then let you do a collection initializer.

Answer (score 3):

First i can't understand why all your properties `private` and `Age` is not `int` type. So my class looks like this:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Childrens { get; set; }
}
```

Note `partial` word. This word will allow you to place your class logic in separate files and this could be usefull when you creating some custom logic in class.

Then I simply create this method in different file:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public Person GetPersonWithChindren(int maxAge)
    {
        return new Person
        {
            Age = this.Age,
            Name = this.Name,
            Childrens = this.Childrens != null 
            ? this.Childrens
                .Where(x => x.Age < maxAge)
                .Select(x => x.GetPersonWithChindren(maxAge)) //this line do recursive magic
                .ToList() 
            : null
        };
    }
}
```

As you can see this method checking `Age` of each child and if `Age` is ok then it checks next level of hierarchy untill `Childrens` is `null`.

So you can use it like this:

```
var person = new Person()
{
  //initialisation of your collection here
}

//result will contains only nodes where Person have age < 4 and Childs that have age < 4
var result = person.GetPersonWithChindren(4);
```

Note that this solution will work normal with **linqToEntities**. But if you using **LinqToSQL** this expression produces query to DB on each `Person` entity. So if you have many Persons and deep hierarhy it will costs you a lot of machine time. In that case you should to write stored procedure with **CTE** instead of LinQ query.

**UPDATE:**

You even can write more general solution with a help of `Func<T>` class like this:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public Person GetPersonWithChindren(Func<Person, bool> func)
    {
        return new Person
        {
            Age = this.Age,
            Name = this.Name,
            Childrens = this.Childrens != null
            ? this.Childrens
                .Where(x => func(x))
                .Select(x => x.GetPersonWithChindren(func))
                .ToList()
            : null
        };
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
var result = person.GetPersonWithChindren(x => x.Age < 4);
```

You always can change your criteria now where you want to use your function.

Comment: I want to do this by using LINQ only...what i meant...can we achieve this by using only LINQ...One linq query on person collection??

Comment: @anandmishra so... I don't use anything else.

Answer (score 3):

Create a visitor. In this example by implementing a helper class:

```
public static class Helpers
public static IEnumerable<Person> GetDescendants(this Person person)
{
    foreach (var child in person.Children)
    {
        yield return child;
        foreach (var descendant in child.GetDescendants())
        {
           yield return descendant;
        }
    }
}
```

this is one of the times where the "yield return many" would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ensuring that `.Children` is automatically created, then this works:

```
Func<Person, Func<Person, bool>, Person> clone = null;
clone = (p, f) => f(p) ? new Person()
{
    Name = p.Name,
    Age = p.Age,
    Children = p.Children.Select(c => clone(c, f)).Where(x => x != null).ToList(),
} : null;

var olderThan4 = clone(person, p => p.Age > 4);
```

Yes, that's it. Effectively three lines.

If you start with this data:

```
var person = new Person()
{
    Name = "Fred", Age = 30,
    Children = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person() { Name = "Bob", Age = 7, },
        new Person() { Name = "Sally", Age = 3, }
    },
};
```

...then you get this result:

[image: result]

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    private List<Person> _children = null;
    public List<Person> Children
    {
        get
        {
            if (_children == null)
            {
                _children = new List<Person>();
            }
            return _children;
        }
        set
        {
            _children = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to write it like this but if I need to get hierarchy not flatten collection?

Comment: @teovankot - You basically want to clone the tree without getting any children that are 4 or under...